# MS Access - Browser to Attach/Move Files not working right

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I found a form that will let you browse for files and attach them to the record, but it actually copies the attachment and puts them into a folder and the file path is saved in the database. This works great...but, I split the database and multiple people will copy the front end to their desktop and work from there. Right now, this code is set up where it will create a new folder or use a folder if already created where the front end is, so in this case it would actually create a folder on the users desktop and this is not what I want. I would like all the attachments to be moved to the server in a central folder and for the database to read files from that folder. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmd_LocateFile_Click()
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
Dim sFile As String
Dim sFolder As String
Dim ID As Long
Dim sTarget As String



sFile = FSBrowse("", msoFileDialogFilePicker, "All Files (*.*),*.*")
If sFile <> "" Then
    sFolder = Application.CodeProject.path & "\" & sAttachmentFolderName & "\"
    If FolderExist(sFolder) = False Then MkDir (sFolder)
    ID = RequestID_FK  ' Set current record id.
sTarget = sFolder & CStr(ID) & "-" & GetFileName(sFile)
If CopyFile(sFile, sFolder & GetFileName(sTarget)) = True Then
        Me!FullFileName.Value = sTarget
    Else
    End If
End If
Error_Handler_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
Exit Sub
Error_Handler:
MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Source: " & sModName & "\cmd_LocateFile_Click" & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
       Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
       , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Sub
```

Here is the rest of the coding

```
'Delete the current attachment/record and the attachment file itself
Private Sub cmd_RecDel_Click()
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
Dim sFile                 As String

sFile = Me.FullFileName
'Delete the database record
DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acEditMenu, 8, , acMenuVer70
DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acEditMenu, 6, , acMenuVer70
'If we're here the record was deleted, so let delete the actual file from the server
Kill sFile

Error_Handler_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
    MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: " & sModName & "\cmd_RecDel_Click" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
           Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
End If
Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Sub

'Open the attachment
Private Sub cmd_ViewFile_Click()
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

Call ExecuteFile(Me.FullFileName, "Open")

Error_Handler_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
Exit Sub
Error_Handler:
MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Source: " & sModName & "\cmd_ViewFile_Click" & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
       Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
       , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Um, just change `sFolder = Application.CodeProject.path & "\" & sAttachmentFolderName & "\"` to whatever folder you want it to be.

Comment: I'm changing it to this, but it's not liking it. Something about end of statement. `sFolder = aiowima23fp1\Ecological Sciences and Engineering\Cultural Resources\New - Cultural Resources Request Database & "\" & sAttachmentFolderName & "\"`

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid string in the comment. Constant strings must be enclosed in double quotes `"mystring"`

Assuming it's a UNC path, this should work:

```
sFolder = "\\aiowima23fp1\Ecological Sciences and Engineering\Cultural Resources\New - Cultural Resources Request Database\" & sAttachmentFolderName & "\"
```

Comment: `sFolder = ("\\aiowima23fp1\Ecological Sciences and Engineering\Cultural Resources\New - Cultural Resources Request Database") & "\" & sAttachmentFolderName & "\"` Seems to be working for me